# Using Power Method to get Eigen-vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

**Edit: please take a look at the comments section**

I learnt that power method converges to the Eigen vector which suits the biggest Eigen value (in absolute value)

Now suppose I have the following Eigen values for matrix $A$ $\{3,1,-3\}$

I can get $v_1$ (which matches $3$) Simply by using power method on $A+I$ -Since the new Eigen values will be $\{4,2,-2\}$ and $v_1$ will have the biggest Eigen value-

Similary, to get $v_3$ I will use power method on $A-I$.

But what about $v_2$, how may I get it?

I thought about making the Eigen values equal to $\{1/3, 1/1, -1/3\}$ But how may I do that?

For example, $A$ is:

[image]

Comment: A is general one, it doesn't matter... Anyway take this for example

Comment: Inverse power iteration. "Multiply" with $A^{-1}$ ie solve the equation repeatedly.

Comment: @Laray may you kindly elaborate? if I multiply with A^(-1) what the Eigen values will be?

Comment: If you solve with $A$ (is essentially the same as multiplying with $A^{-1}$), you use the power method for $A^{-1}$ to get the largest eigenvalue/-vector (in absolute value) of that matrix. This matrix has the EVs you desired ($1/3, 1, -1/3$).

Comment: You solution seems missing a lot of things, may you prove that? I need to prove that: **1)** the new Eigen values will be like this **2)** They share same Eigen vectors **3)** $ A^{-1}$ is defined an exists at all @Laray

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the point of iterative methods if you already know the eigenvalues. Finding an eigenvector is just solving a linear system then.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches you can try.

1. Inverse Power Method:
   This method relies on the usage of $A^{-1}$ for a power iteration, ie you solve a linear system with $A$ repeatedly. You can easily see, that this matrix exists as there are no EVs equal to $0$. Let $\lambda, v$ be an eigenpair of $A$, with $Av=v\lambda$. Then $A^{-1}v = v \lambda^{-1}$ which is easy to prove. This gives that $\lambda^{-1},v$ is an eigenpair of $A^{-1}$. As your matrix $A$ has EVs $(3,1, -3)$ you inverted matrix $A^{-1}$ will have the EVs $(1/3, 1, -1/3)$, where $1$ is the EV with the largest absolute value. This is the limit of the iteration.
2. Power method with projection: After you obtained the eigenvectors for $3$ and $-3$ by shifted power iteration you can find the last eigenvector by using the power iteration and subtract any projection along the already known eigenvectors. This is best used for normal matrices with $AA^T = A^TA$ (for example symmetric or skew-symmetric matrices).

Comment: "which is easy to prove. " may you explain :-)

Comment: You can write $v=A^{-1}Av = A^{-1} v \lambda$. Divide by $\lambda$ on both sides and you got your idea.